# SP_ExecuteSQL;1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-administration

Having a major issues with this procedure called `SP_ExecuteSQL;1`.

It keeps executing internally in SQL Server 2000 with high utilization of CPU. When I pass its SPID in DBCC inputbuffer it shows as internal.

Is there any way of stopping it?

Comment: stopping what? high CPU utilization?

Comment: execution of SP_ExecuteSQL;1.

Comment: I don't even know why it keeps executing internally..

Comment: SP_ExecuteSQL is used to execute dynamic Transact-SQL statements... so the utilization is depend on that dynamic statement, isn't it?

Comment: But i am not executing any dynamic statements here. its internal system Sp which runs most of the time in backend.

Comment: Then a job or an application you did not think of runs it. SQL Server does not usually do it on its own. Use SQL Server Profiler to find out what triggers it and what statements are run.

Comment: One more question: is your IT infrastructure using `Symantec Enterprise Vault` - seems that this app may be the original caller of 'SP_ExecuteSQL;1'

Comment: @Andrey: we were using but its disabled now.

Comment: @Tomalak: It cant run profiler for longer time. Is there any way to find it out.

Comment: Why can't you run the profiler? That doesn't seem plausible to me.

Comment: @Tomalak : its production server, i cant run profiler for a longer time so i am trying to find an alternative for that.

Comment: Is it always run by the same user/login?   Is it a login that you can disable or restrict from running that statement?  By the way, this is probably a question for dba.stackexchange.com, really.

Comment: You can run the Profiler on your own machine, all you need is a connection to the server. Set proper filters (for example "SQL text contains sp_executesql") and see where that leads you. Debugging a problem means using debugging tools, so don't give me that "but I can't use debugging tools", that's nonsense.

Comment: @TabAlleman its run by multiple login and i cannot disable it as they are login of live application.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for suggestion, i will try it and let you know the results.